# .htaccess redirect anchor page/page#anchor to url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, web, anchor

How do I redirect `page/page#anchor` to `http://www.example.com/page/page`.

I tried the following code, but it's not working

```
RewriteRule ^page/page#anchor http://www.example.com/page/page [NE,L]
```

Could you please help me?

Peter

Comment: You are trying to remove the anchor?

Comment: Hello,I have http://www.example.com//page/page# and I need redirect to http://www.example.com/video/photo

Comment: That's still not very helpful ... So you want to make example.com/page/page/#anchor example.com/page/page?  You want to remove the hashtag/anchor?

Comment: This is my old link o-firme/videoprezentace#omezeni my new link is o-firme/videoprezentace/navody-a-tutorialy. I need redirect o-firme/videoprezentace#omezeni to o-firme/videoprezentace/navody-a-tutorialy

Answer (score 4):

That can't be done on server side since URI component after `#` is handled by client side only.

You can alternatively use this Javascript code to do the same:

```
<script>
if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
   location.assign(location.href.replace(/(page\/page)#anchor/i, "$1"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looking at your comment in question you will need: `location.assign(location.href.replace(/(videoprezentace)#omezeni/i, "$1/navody-a-tutorialy"));`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the data after `#` is considered a fragment.  Fragment data is not sent to the server.  Therefore you cannot capture it using modrewrite.

the `NE` flag may let you capture  `^/page/page` and redirect to `http://www.example.com/page/page#anchor` but it won't work the other way around.

A simple JavaScript replace will replace the links and allow the users to click on them.  But that won't help you with SEO if that is your ultimate goal.