# Replace/Redirect URL which include anchor link (#)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress website.
I want to redirect the old url example.com/submenu/7?s=question#anchor_top to example.com/one/two/

This cannot be done through .htaccess because of the #, so I guess have to enter a javascript code into the .

I tried this: [.htaccess redirect anchor page/page#anchor to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503529/htaccess-redirect-anchor-page-pageanchor-to-url)
but it was redirecting to example.com/one/two/?s=question#anchor_top

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

it' two way to possible.

1. add rewrite rule
2. redirection Plugin.

try this plugin

i) https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Read this article.

ii)https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

i) I have tried the plugin but it the redirection of #anchor links is not working with it.


ii) Can you assist if the code I wrote is correct for my example
(example.com/submenu/7?s=question#anchor_top to redirect to example.com/one/two/)

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^/one/two/+)/?', 'submenu', 'top/7?s=question#anchor_top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');