# Move site from angular to another: how to make 301 redirect URLs from old to new ?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, url, redirect

The problem is next:
Site was created on agular and now we moved that to Wordpress, Urls changed and I have no idea how to make 301 redirect.

for example:

old url: /#!architecture/cwj3
new urL: /אדריכלות/

Redirection plugin isn't workin, becouse it's look like anchor link.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503529/htaccess-redirect-anchor-page-pageanchor-to-url)
    
    if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
       location.assign(location.href.replace(/(page/page)#anchor/i, "$1"));
    }